# Need Help Bundling Extras

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Implementing the following null check in my new Java class (Tap.java):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "received no extras!");
```

Results in:

```
ViewCountry(11637): received no extras!
```

Therefore I believe I'll need to bundle extras to the new class I've created (Tap.java) as well as the existing class it is currently bundled to (ViewCountry.java) from my CountryList.java.

How can this be accomplished?

The following bundle is the one I'd like to expand to include the same data (ROW_ID, arg3):

```
Intent viewCon = new Intent(CountryList.this, ViewCountry.class);
          viewCon.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
          startActivity(viewCon);
```

How can this be expanded to send data to Tap.java as well?

```
public class Tap extends Enable {

    private static final String TAG = ViewCountry.class.getName();

    protected Message message;

    NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    private static final int MESSAGE_SENT = 1;
    private long rowID;
    private TextView nameTv;
    private TextView capTv;
    private TextView codeTv;
    private TextView timeTv;
    private TextView ssidTv;
    private TextView combined;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_country);
        setDetecting(true);
        startPushing();
        setUpViews();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        rowID = extras.getLong(CountryList.ROW_ID);
    }

    private void setUpViews() {
        nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        capTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capText);
        timeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
        codeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeText);
        ssidTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiSSID);


    }

    @Override
    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Create message to be beamed");
        String a = "";
        String b = "";
        String message1 = a + ssidTv.getText().toString() + ","
                + capTv.getText().toString() + b;

        // create message to be pushed, for example
        Message message = new Message();
        // add text record
        message.add(new TextRecord(message1));
        // add 'my' external type record
    //  message.add(new GenericExternalTypeRecord("com.wifi.demo", "atype",
        //      "My data".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));

        // encode to NdefMessage, will be pushed via beam (now!) (unless there
        // is a collision)
        return message.getNdefMessage();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Implementation of {@link OnNdefPushCompleteCallback} interface.
     * 
     * This method is called after a successful transfer (push) of a message
     * from this device to another.
     */

    @Override
    protected void onNdefPushCompleteMessage() {
        // make toast
        toast(R.string.nfcBeamed);

        // vibrate
        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibe.vibrate(500);
    }

    public void toast(int id) {
        toast(getString(id));
    }

    public void toast(String message) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,
                0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * NFC was found and enabled in settings, and push is enabled too.
     * 
     */

    @Override
    protected void onNfcPushStateEnabled() {
        toast(getString(R.string.nfcBeamAvailableEnabled));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * NFC was found and enabled in settings, but push is disabled
     * 
     */

    @Override
    protected void onNfcPushStateDisabled() {
        toast(getString(R.string.nfcBeamAvailableDisabled));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * NFC beam setting changed since last check. For example, the user enabled
     * beam in the wireless settings.
     * 
     */

    @Override
    protected void onNfcPushStateChange(boolean enabled) {
        if (enabled) {
            toast(getString(R.string.nfcBeamAvailableEnabled));
        } else {
            toast(getString(R.string.nfcBeamAvailableDisabled));
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * NFC feature was found and is currently enabled
     * 
     */

    @Override
    protected void onNfcStateEnabled() {
        toast(getString(R.string.nfcAvailableEnabled));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * NFC feature was found but is currently disabled
     * 
     */

    @Override
    protected void onNfcStateDisabled() {
        toast(getString(R.string.nfcAvailableDisabled));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * NFC setting changed since last check. For example, the user enabled NFC
     * in the wireless settings.
     * 
     */

    @Override
    protected void onNfcStateChange(boolean enabled) {
        if (enabled) {
            toast(getString(R.string.nfcAvailableEnabled));
        } else {
            toast(getString(R.string.nfcAvailableDisabled));
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * This device does not have NFC hardware
     * 
     */

    @Override
    protected void onNfcFeatureNotFound() {
        toast(getString(R.string.noNfcMessage));
    }

    /**
     * An NDEF message was read and parsed
     * 
     * @param message
     *            the message
     */

    @Override
    protected void readNdefMessage(Message message) {
        if (message.size() > 1) {
            toast(getString(R.string.readMultipleRecordNDEFMessage));
        } else {
            toast(getString(R.string.readSingleRecordNDEFMessage));
        }
    }

    /**
     * An empty NDEF message was read.
     * 
     */

    @Override
    protected void readEmptyNdefMessage() {
        toast(getString(R.string.readEmptyMessage));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Something was read via NFC, but it was not an NDEF message.
     * 
     * Handling this situation is out of scope of this project.
     * 
     */

    @Override
    protected void readNonNdefMessage() {
        toast(getString(R.string.readNonNDEFMessage));
    }

    // mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    // if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
    // / nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    // nameTv.setText("NFC is not available on this device.");
    // capTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capText);
    // capTv.setText("NFC is not available on this device.");
    // codeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeText);
    // codeTv.setText("NFC is not available on this device.");
    // timeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
    // timeTv.setText("NFC is not available on this device.");
    // } else {
    // mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
    // mNfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(this, this);
    // }
    // }

    // @Override
    // public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {

    // String a="\"";
    // String b="\"";

    // String message1 = a + ssidTv.getText().toString() +"," +
    // capTv.getText().toString()+b;
    // String message2 = nameTv.getText().toString();
    // String message3 = codeTv.getText().toString();
    // String message4 = timeTv.getText().toString();
    // byte[] textBytes1 = message1.getBytes();
    // byte[] textBytes2 = message2.getBytes();
    // byte[] textBytes3 = message3.getBytes();
    // byte[] textBytes4 = message4.getBytes();
    // NdefRecord textRecord1 = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,
    // message1.getBytes(), new byte[] {}, textBytes1);
    // NdefRecord textRecord2 = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,
    // message2.getBytes(), new byte[] {}, textBytes2);
    // NdefRecord textRecord3 = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,
    // message3.getBytes(), new byte[] {}, textBytes3);
    // NdefRecord textRecord4 = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,
    // message4.getBytes(), new byte[] {}, textBytes4);

    // NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {textRecord1,
    // textRecord2, textRecord3, textRecord4,
    // NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.nfc.linked") });
    // return msg;

    // /**
    // * Implementation for the OnNdefPushCompleteCallback interface
    // */
    // @Override
    // public void onNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent arg0) {
    // mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_SENT).sendToTarget();
    // }

    // /** This handler receives a message from onNdefPushComplete */
    // private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    // @Override
    // public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    // switch (msg.what) {
    // case MESSAGE_SENT:
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    // "Core Device Rules Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // break;
    // }
    // }
    // };

    // @Override
    // public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    // setIntent(intent);
    // }

    // void processIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent
    // .getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
    // NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
    // nameTv.setText(new String(msg.getRecords()[0].getPayload()));
    // }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
    }

    private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> {
        DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(Tap.this);

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params) {
            dbConnector.open();
            return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            result.moveToFirst();
            int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("name");
            int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("cap");
            int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("code");
            int timeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("time");
            int ssidIndex = result.getColumnIndex("ssid");

            nameTv.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
            capTv.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
            timeTv.setText(result.getString(timeIndex));
            codeTv.setText(result.getString(codeIndex));
            ssidTv.setText(result.getString(ssidIndex));

            result.close();
            dbConnector.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_country_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.editItem:
            Intent addEditContact = new Intent(this, AddEditDevice.class);

            // addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
            // addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
            // addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
            // addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());
            startActivity(addEditContact);
            return true;

        case R.id.user1SettingsSave:
            Intent Tap = new Intent(this, ViewCountry.class);
            startActivity(Tap);
            return true;

        case R.id.deleteItem:
            deleteContact();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void deleteContact() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tap.this);

        alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle);
        alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage);

        alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button) {
                        final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(
                                Tap.this);

                        AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask = new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>() {
                            @Override
                            protected Object doInBackground(Long... params) {
                                dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]);
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        };

                        deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });
                    }
                });

        alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
    }

}
```

CountryList.java

```
public class CountryList extends ListActivity {

     public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
     private ListView conListView;
     private CursorAdapter conAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        conListView=getListView();
        conListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewConListener);

        // map each name to a TextView
        String[] from = new String[] { "name" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.countryTextView };
        conAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(CountryList.this, R.layout.country_list, null, from, to);
        setListAdapter(conAdapter); // set adapter
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
       super.onResume();  
       new GetContacts().execute((Object[]) null);
     } 


    @Override
    protected void onStop() 
    {
       Cursor cursor = conAdapter.getCursor();

       if (cursor != null) 
          cursor.deactivate();

       conAdapter.changeCursor(null);
       super.onStop();
    }    


    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> 
    {
       DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(CountryList.this);

       @Override
       protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params)
       {
          dbConnector.open();
          return dbConnector.getAllContacts(); 
       } 

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
       {
          conAdapter.changeCursor(result); // set the adapter's Cursor
          dbConnector.close();
       } 
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.country_menu, menu);
       return true;
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
       Intent addContact = new Intent(CountryList.this, AddEditDevice.class);
       startActivity(addContact);
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    OnItemClickListener viewConListener = new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
       {         
          Intent viewCon = new Intent(CountryList.this, ViewCountry.class);
          viewCon.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
          startActivity(viewCon);
       }
    };    

}
```

LOGCAT:

```
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wifi.demo/com.wifi.demowifi.demo.Tap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at com.wifi.demo.Tap.onCreate(Tap.java:75)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-16 13:37:22.415: E/AndroidRuntime(10285):    ... 11 more
04-16 13:37:25.315: D/libEGL(10339): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
04-16 13:37:25.345: D/libEGL(10339): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
04-16 13:37:25.355: D/libEGL(10339): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
04-16 13:37:25.385: D/OpenGLRenderer(10339): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: Too little code. Not enough to put our team of developers to work on it, sorry.

Comment: Bundle may null check if extras!=null

Comment: whers the code extras.getLong(CountryList.ROW_ID);

Comment: can you check extras is getting null

Comment: Added CountryList.java

Comment: I added my null check results

Comment: Help! Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seem that when you start your second activity, you don't pass any data through your Intent

To make it more clear, you have to do the same that you do when you call "ViewCountry"

```
  Intent viewCon = new Intent(CountryList.this, ViewCountry.class);
  viewCon.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
  startActivity(viewCon);
```

Comment: I don't need to pass data from Tap to View Country - I need to pass data from ViewCountry to Tap

Comment: so where's your calling to "startActivity(new Intent(context, Tap.class));" ?

Comment: I don't think I one is required - I add the data to my database using AddEditCountry.java then I can view a list  data entries by viewing CountryList.java then I can see the details of each entry by using ViewCountry.java I now want to view the daya originally accessed  by ViewCountry (using bundle extras from CountryList) in my new file Tap.java (which is where I am having a problem: bundling extras from CountryList to Tap.java - they are currently bundled so ViewCountry has access to the data - I simply need to allow Tap.java to access the same data - make sense?)

Comment: It sounds more complicated than it is... I just need to bundle the same extras that are currently shown in CountryList (pointing to ViewCountry) to Tap.java

Comment: I'm assuming that Tap.java is an Activity (Tap extends Enable, so I'm assuming that Enable extends Activity). That's why I think it's necessary to have a call to startActivity, starting the Activity "Tap" with the same extras that ViewCountry has.